# How to control the style of the default valueLabelComponent of material ui Slider?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

[image]

It is too large and the background color isn't right.

So the solution is:

1. Change the size and background color of the default `valueLabelComponent`.
2. Create a component that has the same shape as the default with the correct size and color, of course.

Either solution would be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the size of the value label component is not customizable according to this [ticket](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20911). You can use [withStyles](https://next.material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) to customize your own style on the same component. I have created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2c0ju?file=/demo.js) code sandbox where you can change the size and color keeping the same style.

Furthermore, you can create your own component and pass it to a slider prop name `ValueLabelComponent` but for that, you need to play around with the CSS. Follow [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/h0esn) example for creating custom value label component.

Comment: thanks. worked. additionally, how would I change the color based on the value of the slider?

Comment: For that create a wrapper for value label component and add prop for color to set on background color, then use `onChange` call back, inside it compute your color with respect to the slider value and then set state of corresponding state used for value label component color